# .then((userCredential) => { } not working with firebase authentification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a web application (beginner level) and I use firebase for authentification and database. I can create a new account and register it on my firebase authentification dashboard without issue, but nothing inside .then((userCredential) => { } is working (alerts don't show up, I can't register the account on firebase database etc....
I checked on chrome console and no errors show up, and I have no error messages from .catch as well.
How can I fix this so what's inside .then is working?
Thank you!

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js' 
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-auth.js'
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, getDocs, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-firestore.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "" 
  };


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth(); 
const database = getDatabase()


submitData.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var name = document.getElementById('full_name').value
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('psw').value;
    alert(email)
    // do verification




    // Move on with Auth
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {

      const user = userCredential.user
      alert("user created")
    })
    
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Firebase will use this to alert of its errors
      var error_code = error.code
      var error_message = error.message

       alert(error_message)
      alert('not working')
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you need `e.preventDefault()` to stop the page from reloading?

Comment: The page always reload after I sign-up. Where would I write e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: Is this the way your `firebaseConfig` looks like?

Comment: @tmarwen On the actual code I filled everything inside the quotation marks.

Comment: If you're using form element then just use `e.preventDefault()` to stop page from reloading, place it before the variables

Comment: Thank you so much @SuhailQureshi ! I added e.preventDefault() and it's working fine now.

Comment: @AIRONE glad it worked for ya!

Comment: @SuhailQureshi Post this as an answer, below, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `form` element then just use `e.preventDefault()` to stop page from reloading, place it before the variables.